# Cluster a vmware server between two cluster nodes

Tags: vmware-server, failover, windows-cluster

we run a vmware server 1.0 on one node of our Windows failover cluster. As this is a failover cluster we want to be able to cluster the vmware server to another node. Is that possible without concern? The vmware disks can be put on a san to be switched between the nodes as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose technically it would be possible.  It would be a much better solution to purchase some VMware vSphere licenses and setup a vSphere Cluster so that you get the native HA which comes with VMware ESX.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sufficient $$$ for getting a SAN appliance you can always use DRBD which is basically a raid1 over network. You can mirror a block device from one physical node to another. But you will have to run Linux on the node.

Answer (score 0):

VMware server is not the product that you'd wish to do this with. As mrdenny suggested, either go up to vSphere.

OR.

Re-evaluate what you are using VMware Server for, and if you need the failover feature-set, and obviously have access to a SAN - your best bet without spending actual $ would be to go with XenServer - which will provide you with HA.

One thing to note is that it will require a dedicated machine (something to consider, as it seems whatever workload you're trying to virtualize is important enough that you're considering failover)

Comment: acutally, the vmware is not that important. It only runs on one node of the failover cluster. The failover is for other applications. But I think it would be good to be able to cluster the vmware to another node, if that node fails for a longer term of time. So the questions is, how to cluster the basic vmware server?